# when i append something using the append function i dont have control over it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is a simple demonstration of what i have, this is a table with a single row in it,

```
<table id="test_table">
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>age</td>
        <td>action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test name</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td class="delete">delete</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and if i click on the delete td this row would be hidden

```
  $('.delete').click(function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().hide();
  });
```

and i have a simple form of name and age, when i click on the add button it appends it to the table

```
 $('#test_input').click(function(){
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var age = $('#age').val();
        $('#text_table').append('<tr><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+age+'</td><td     class="delete">delete</td></tr>');
  });
```

the problem is i if i click on the new appended row it would hide like its not even there, what ever i try to do using the appended row, it wouldn't take it, is there something wrong that im doing ?

Comment: Can you show the *full* [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) code, including the buttons and inputs?

Comment: After fixing this, you'll find that your delete button won't work on the new row. Have a read about [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 0):

`$('#test_table')` should be `$('#test-table')`.

And you should bind the on-click on the added row.

Another solution is to create a [delegated event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: sorry it is already like tht, that was a typo coz i wrote it from another laptop, what do u mean exactly?

Comment: @hatsjoem i did the on-click and it worked, i'll implement that with what i have and hopefully it'll work, thanks